# Customise Stripe success page in Svelte without Express

Tags: stripe-payments, svelte, sveltekit

## The problem

I would like to display a customer name on the Stripe success page within SvelteKit app.

There is a handy tutorial on how to do it - [Customize your success page](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page) by Stripe, but the example sets up an endpoint on Node using the Express framework which I would like to avoid.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_26PHem9AhJZvU623DfE1x4sd');

app.get('/order/success', async (req, res) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(req.query.session_id);
  const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(session.customer);

  res.send(`<html><body><h1>Thanks for your order, ${customer.name}!</h1></body></html>`);
});

app.listen(4242, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${4242}!`));
```

## My code (updated)

Success route looks like this - `http://localhost:5173/success?session_id=cs_test_123456789`

My `success` route contains `+page.svelte` file which makes a `fetch` request to `+server.js` which has the following code aligned with a documentation in [SvelteKit Routing](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server) documentation:

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';
import { STRIPE_SECRET_KEY } from '$env/static/private';

import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit';

const stripe = new Stripe(STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export async function GET ( req ) {
    console.log(req.url.searchParams.get('session_id'));

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(req.url.searchParams.get('session_id'));
    const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(session.customer);
    console.log(`${customer.name}, thanks for subscribing!`);

    return json(customer);
}
```

The `console.log(req.url.searchParams.get('session_id'));` returns `null` when in theory a string with `session_id` should be expected. Subsequently, Stripe returns an error - `Error: Stripe: Argument "session" must be a string, but got: null (on API request to` GET /v1/checkout/sessions/{session}`)`. If I replace `req.url.searchParams.get('session_id')` with an actual session_id `'cs_test_123456789'` everything is fine and I am able to retrieve customer's name.

## Solutions?

It seems to me that query string parameter (session_id) should be extracted first from the URL and passed on to a GET call, but to the best of my knowledge I would have to create a third file `+page.js` with `export function load({ url })` to extract `searchParams`.

Do I miss something and there is a short and elegant solution to this?

## Alternative solution

I found replies from @h-b below and [sveltekit-stripe-subscriptions](https://github.com/joshnuss/sveltekit-stripe-subscriptions/blob/main/src/routes/checkout/complete/%2Bpage.server.js) repo on GitHub by Joshua Nussbaum very helpful. I renamed `+server.js` as `+page.server.js` within `success` route and used following code:

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';
import { STRIPE_SECRET_KEY } from '$env/static/private';

const stripe = new Stripe(STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export async function load({ url }) {
    const session_id = url.searchParams.get('session_id')

    // ask Stripe for a full object of the session
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(session_id)

    // ask Stripe for a customer linked to the session
    const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(session.customer)
    
    // ask Stripe for a name of the customer
    let customer_name = customer.name

    return {
        customer_name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server) and associated types. The event object has a `url` parameter which is a [web standard `URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL).

So if you call the event object `req` it's just:

```js
req.url.searchParams.get('session_id')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this before, but `console.log(req.url.searchParams.get('session_id'));` returns `null`, not a string object. Subsequently, Stripe API returns an error - `Stripe: Argument "session" must be a string, but got: null`.

Comment: You seem to have mixed up something about the file organization or checkout procedure. The endpoint is supposed to be called by Stripe, but you wrote something about your own page fetching it. The page should start the checkout, [send the URL to go to on success to Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page#modify-success-url), and Stripe then redirects back setting the parameter.

Comment: The checkout works perfectly with customer redirected to `success url` just fine. My file structure is barebone and looks like this: `src > routes > +page.svelte` home page containing pricing table and ` form action` which after `low code` integration of stripe checkout with code in `+page.server.js` redirects to a `src > routes > success > +page.svelte` which takes the form of `http://localhost:5173/success?session_id=cs_test_123456789`. Are you trying to suggest that GET request with `req.url.searchParams.get('session_id')` should be placed within checkout file `+page.server.js` with POST?

Comment: No, it should be in your success route. DId you check the full `url` object? If the URL looks as you claimed, including the query string, it should be retrievable with the given code.

Comment: Unfortunately it returns `null`, not a `string` object and subsequently, Stripe API returns an error - `Stripe: Argument "session" must be a string, but got: null`.

Comment: I was talking about the `url`, if said `url` were itself `null`, the property access `searchParams` would already throw an error. The first question is what URL ends up in the event and whether the parameter is there or not.

Comment: This is `url` of a success page `http://localhost:5173/success?session_id=cs_test_123456789`. `session_id` is a parameter.

Comment: If that is actually what `req.url` contains, I see *no* reason why the parameter should not be read correctly. Just execute `new URL('http://localhost:5173/success?session_id=cs_test_123456789').searchParams.get('session_id')` in the browser or Node.

Comment: It is read correctly in both the browser and Node with `new URL('http://localhost:5173/success?session_id=cs_test_123456789').searchParams.get('session_id')` provided by you. Any ideas to why `req.url.searchParams.get('session_id')` is not doing the same?

Comment: No, I do not, which is why I suspected that `req.url` is not what you claim it to be.

Comment: The only way I managed to make it work is to rename my `+server.js` file within `success` route into `page.server.js` and use `export async function load({ url }) {...}` as mentioned in my original potential solution.